# Denied entry at the Canadian land border; will I be denied if I fly?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, denial-of-entry

I recently was denied entry into Canada, due to me wanting to bring my other wheels for my vehicle to store them at a U-Haul facility until I started school in Canada in the Spring.

They thought that, because I was bringing my wheels, I was trying to stay illegally until school begins. Also, I don't have my study permit just yet. They thought I would come and hang  around to get it when school started.

My main reason for going was to spend the holidays with my girlfriend. I really want to spend the holidays with her. If I bought a plane ticket to Canada, would they have my refusal on record and deny me at the airport as well?

Comment: Were you actually denied entry or did they allow you to withdraw your application to enter?

Comment: You’re right, on the paper I was given it says I withdrew my application, is there a difference?

Comment: That's the lowest level of refusal, basically they're saying you haven't done anything wrong, but we're not convinced you won't.  Come back when this isn't an issue, such as when you student visa becomes valid.

Answer (score 4):

They will have it in the record, yes.

However, if you can prove through documentation that you don't intend to violate the terms of your stay, you can still be let in, whether at a land border or airport.

Comment: What documents should I use in my case?